# How can i save cookie in javascript then access it in another page using php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to know which link was clicked so i can show the page content accordingly.
here is what i have:

first page:

```
 <script>
function click(index){
    if (index == 'Requests')
        document.cookie = "clicked="+ index +";path=/";}


</script>

   <?php 

    foreach ($boxData as $index => $element){
   echo " <a href=$element onclick=click($index)><div id='blue_box'></div>
        <div id='grey_box'>$index</div></a>";}

    ?>
```

Second page:

```
if ($_COOKIE['clicked'] == 'Requests'){
  $boxData_2 = array (
"List of request" => "",
"Make a New Request" => "",
 "List of Employee Request" => ""
);}
  else if ($_COOKIE['Assets']){
      $boxData_2 = array (
"Add a new Assets" => "",
"List of Assets" => "",
);
  }
```

the error is 
Undefined index: clicked

what am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `$boxData` look like? Is `index == 'Requests'` ever happening? Did you check in your browser if the cookie gets set? And why not use url parameters and $_GET instead?

Comment: @ChrisG  $boxData is an array to save the labels for printing and it works without the cookie idea. and no the cookie is not set in browser.What do you mean by using url parameters and $_GET?

Comment: The most basic PHP navigation is to use `<a href="index.php?page=whatever&subpage=somesub">` and in `index.php` grab `$_GET['page']` and `$_GET['subpage']` to display the respective content.

Comment: @ChrisG the content will be displayed on the same page but the only difference will be weather the user clicked on Requests or Assets.The labels displayed will be different.

Comment: So? What's your point? Cookies are not necessary to implement a navigation. And you only need one script, index.php.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, i finally understood your point and it works.